# django query optimization in iteration

Tags: django, optimization

```
class Value(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....
```

1.

```
for attribute in attributes:
    attribute.value = Value.objects.get(Q(attribute__id=attribute.id) & Q(platform__id=platform.id))
```

2.

```
values = Value.objects.filter(platform__id=platform.id)

for attribute in attributes:
    attribute.value = values.get(attribute__id=attribute.id)
```

Can I say the method 2 is more efficient than 1 because it prevents excessive DB query?

Comment: Please post your Value and Attribute models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 2 can be reduced to only 1 DB query like so:

```
values = Value.objects.filter(platform__id=platform.id)
attribute_values = {value.attribute_id: value for value in values}

for attribute in attributes:
    attribute.value = attribute_values[attribute.id]
```

I'm assuming that Value.attribute is a ForeignKey

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that's the case, because `filter` and `get` are just building up some `where` statements for sql query. You might think that django is caching the value `values` because you only do it once, but the query is not even evaluated when you do:

```
values = Value.objects.filter(platform__id=platform.id)
```

Every time you call `get`, it's adding a `where` statement upon the `filter` statement and hit the database to fetch the results, so you don't gain anything in terms of performance.

By the way, `Value.objects.get(Q(attribute__id=attribute.id) & Q(platform__id=platform.id))` is the same as:

```
Value.objects.get(attribute=attribute, platform=platform)
```

which is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and advice. I would ask how I can improve the first method if the both are same. I worry about large number of db access degrades disk performance. Or do you think I don't have to worry about it

Comment: Yea it will hurt your performance, but caching the data manually would solve the problem(if your data could fit in your memory). Sounds like Iain is faster than me and his answer should solve your problem, but I do want you to understand the mechanism of django queries.